# Ansible variable check in playbook

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

I have in the vars file the databases configured as the following:

```
project_dbs:
  - { project_db_name: "project1", project_db_user: "user", tenon_db_password: "pass" }
  - { project_db_name: "project2",  project_db_user: "dev", tenon_db_password: "pass2"}
  - { project_db_name: "project3", project_db_user: "{{datadog_mysql_username}}", project_db_password: "{{datadog_mysql_password}}" }
```

Now in a playbook I have a check:

```
 - name: copy config.json template to server
   tags: provision
   template: src=config.json dest={{ project_root }}/config
   when: item.project_db_name == "project2"
   with_items: project_dbs
```

But the when check is failing. Any idea how to make that work?

The error message looks like this:

> fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'item.projects_db_name == \"project2\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.projects_db_name == \"project2\"): 'unicode object' has no attribute 'projects_db_name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/project/ansible/roles/project2/tasks/main.yml': line 28, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: copy config.json template to server\n  ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an outdated syntax called "bare variables" in `with_items`:

```
with_items: project_dbs
```

This way your `item` becomes a string object with the value of `project_dbs` and Ansible reports it doesn't have the attribute ("'unicode object' has no attribute 'projects_db_name'").

In Ansible 2.x you should quote variables in the following way:

```
with_items: "{{ project_dbs }}"
```

---

That said, your task makes no use of the values from the loop. The following will have the same effect:

```
- name: copy config.json template to server
  tags: provision
  template: src=config.json dest={{ project_root }}/config
```

Comment: Ansible warns on bare variables now. If they're not seeing that warning, I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 And the error message actually confirms that a bare variable is the problem.

Comment: I'm assuming that they do in fact use the variables but that they're not giving a real example of the task.

Comment: That is wrong. That's the exact code we have. The database config it is in the group_vars/test

Comment: Good. Then it's my full answer. Nothing to add.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `when` you could just filter the list of project_dbs so it looks like this:

```
- name: "copy config.json template to server"
  tags: provision
  template: src=config.json dest={{ project_root }}/config
  with_items: "{{ project_dbs | selectattr("project_db_name", "project2") }}"
```

Comment: Actually I want to check if the projects2 is configured and only then run the task.

Comment: I am asking what would be the correct form of check so that the task would not fail.

Comment: I know what you intended, and for a moment I even added a reference to your answer, but this code makes no sense. You can remove `with_items` altogether.

Comment: OK, so there is the environment, What I want to achieve to run the task only if the database exist. Can I have a suggestion for a correct code to achive that?